# Does ZFS support something like "nodatacow" of BTRFS?

Tags: linux, zfs, btrfs, snapshot

This is a follow up to a [former question](https://superuser.com/q/1188922/308859) about BTRFS and in the end I want to have a file system supporting at least the manual creation of snapshots for backup and test purposes. The data I'm hosting is mostly VMs, most likely dynamically growing and the VMs itself contain web servers and some associated web apps with a PostgreSQL cluster for data storage.

I've read about [different](https://blog.pgaddict.com/posts/friends-dont-let-friends-use-btrfs-for-oltp) [benchmarks](https://www.slideshare.net/fuzzycz/postgresql-on-ext4-xfs-btrfs-and-zfs) how BTRFS and [ZFS](https://www.slideshare.net/SeanChittenden/postgresql-zfs-best-practices) perform hosting VMs or in combination with PostgreSQL and especially [BTRFS is stating](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas#Fragmentation) that `CoW` should be avoided in such workloads. No problem, `nodatacow` to the rescue, but unfortunately it [deactivates checksumming](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mount_options) as well.

But how about ZFS as a possible alternative? Does it provide some comparable option to reduce `CoW` to only manually created snapshots by keeping things like checksumming? I didn't find anything regarding this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't -- copy-on-write is heavily ingrained in ZFS' design -- but you may be interested in my old (2013) question [What are the performance implications of running VMs on a ZFS host?](https://serverfault.com/q/532272/58408) on [sf].